# Jmeter script not recording Google map

Tags: google-maps, jmeter, recording

I'm trying recording script using Jmeter 2.7.
I've set proxy and also added HTTP Proxy Server in Jmeter Workbench with the port 8080.

My application only has to load Google maps with certain colors highlighted on it, after the User logs in.
While recording the script, there's no issue till User login. After login, the User lands on correct page but there's no Google map on it. I tried the same activity again & again but no luck.

Can anybody help please???

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Google API (aka GWT) makes heavy use of client-side Javascript.

IMHO, the data exchanged on http protocol are very hard to be emulated inside a custom client.

I resolved to use selenium-webdriver so that the browser makes all the work.
HTH